# unable to install bcrypt on an ipv6 only host on ubuntu 20.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm, ipv6

this worked fine for an ipv4 supporting host, when I got the ipv6 only hosts from vultr.com
Its causing an issue.

in my package.json I've got the following line for bcrypt

`"bcrypt": "^5.0.0",`

when running npm I'm getting the following failures.

```
> bcrypt@5.0.0 install /var/www/production/source/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@5.0.0 and node@14.15.0 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error connect ENETUNREACH 140.82.112.4:443 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ENETUNREACH 104.20.23.46:443 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
gyp ERR! stack     at internalConnect (net.js:921:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:429:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitLookup [as callback] (net.js:1064:9)
gyp ERR! stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:69:8)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-25-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/var/www/production/source/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/var/www/production/source/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/production/source/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/var/www/production/source/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/var/www/production/source/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/www/production/source/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-25-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/var/www/production/source/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/production/source/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.15.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/var/www/production/source/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/var/www/production/source/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm WARN acorn-jsx@5.2.0 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@2.20.2 requires a peer of eslint@2.x - 6.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN notification-server@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-13T11_08_58_941Z-debug.log
```

I read online that Im required to add the routing to the npm registry in the `/etc/hosts`
like so

`2606:4700::6810:1723 registry.npmjs.org`

but still doesn't work for bcrypt.

Comment: It may be easier to pay the extra $1 per month for an ipv4 address - it may be that there are some resources required that don't have an IPv4 address ... `140.82.112.4` and `104.20.23.46` have nothing to do with `registry.npmjs.org` so your hosts entry won't help

Comment: `don't have an IPv4 address` of course, I meant to say ***only** have an IPv4 address*

Comment: `104.20.23.46` is odd, that's one of `nodejs.org`s IP's ... nodejs.org definitley has IPv6 addresses

Comment: @JaromandaX ill feel like I got defeated if I have to pay that extra 1$ :)